# How to build an optimal tree given items costs and edge costs?

Tags: trees, binary-tree, combinatorics

Given:

- a list of 'leaves' that each have a cost,
- the cost of creating an 'edge'
- The constraint that a constructed tree node can at most have two children.

We now want to find the tree with the lowest maximum cost when adding up the cost of edges from each leaf up to the root node.

When naïvely attempting to build all different possible binary trees, one sees that this takes `O(C(n))` steps, where C(n) is the `n`-th [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)

A simple dynamic programming-solution is isomorph with solving the [Matrix Chain Multiplication Ordering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication), but filling the matrix used by this algorithm will take a ridiculous amount of memory.

I expect that it is possible to find a solution that is a lot more efficient (both in terms of time and memory).

How can you find out what the optimal tree structure would be?

How can you determine what the highest cost (cost of the leaf node + cost of the edges between it and the root node) would be in such a tree?

Comment: You seem to have have left something out: what constraint do you have on your trees such that you're searching through all possible trees?

Comment: @walpen I have added the sentence "We want to find the tree with the lowest cost". Does that clarify it, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, but isn't a balanced tree the one with the least number of edges and thus the one with the minimal total cost?

Comment: @DanielJour The 'total cost' does not change between a balanced tree and an unbalanced one, as the amount of edges remains the same. But the maximum of (leaf node cost + edges up to root cost) does change.

Comment: The amount of edges is not the same: consider two leaves. Case one: a root node holding the two leaves. Two edges. Case two: a single inner node below root holding the two leaves. Three edges.

Comment: @DanielJour: The amount of edges is always |nodes|-1. There is no reason to add additional inner nodes.

Comment: @LiorKogan Indeed, that's what I was trying to make clear. "build[ing] all possible binary trees" is thus completely unnecessary. One just needs the one with the minimum number of nodes.

Comment: @Qqwy What do you want to minimize? The sum of the cost of all the edges plus the sum of the cost of all the leaves? Or is a leave going to get more costly when its deeper down in the tree?

Comment: @DanielJour I want to build a minimal tree such that `max(for leaf ∈ leaves: leaf cost + edge costs up to root)` is as low as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The number of edges is [constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454639/how-many-edges-does-an-undirected-tree-with-n-nodes-have).

You should construct a [Huffman tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), and use the cost of each leaf as the frequency.